# Pass option select variable with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Noob here trying to do something simple with Jquery. Basically I have a small select-option dropdown like this:

```
<select onchange="javascript:swapContent('con3');">
    <option>selection 1</option>
    <option>selection 2</option>
    <option>selection 3</option>
</select>
```

Currently it is posted via ajax to a $php variable here:

```
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
```

javascript function is here:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#myDiv").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "myphpscript.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
        $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });    
}
</script>
```

How can I instead post the value of the select-option dropdown?

I realize this is basic, but I have to start somewhere and cannot find a tutorial that shows me how to do what I need.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: By "select-option" do you mean the value of the selected option in the select control?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I instead post the value of the select-option dropdown?

If you want to send values yo tour script you should start by giving values to your option elements (and an id to your `<select>` element  to be able to use it and retrieve the selected value):

```
<select onchange="javascript:swapContent('con3');" id="myselect">
    <option value="value1">selection 1</option>
    <option value="value2">selection 2</option>
    <option value="value3">selection 3</option>
</select>
```

and then:

```
// get the currently selected value from the dropdown
var value = $('#myselect').val();
$.post(url, { contentVar: cv, selectedValue: value }, function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
});
```

If on the other hand you wanted to send the text of the selected option you could use this:

```
// get the currently selected value from the dropdown
var text = $('#myselect option:selected').text();
$.post(url, { contentVar: cv, selectedText: text }, function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
});
```

Now inside your PHP script you could fetch the value:

```
$_POST['selectedValue']
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**:

Remove the inline javascript change event from the select.

```
<select>
  <option>selection 1</option>
  <option>selection 2</option>
  <option>selection 3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**:

Bind a change event to your select. Inside this event, `this.value` with be the value of the select.

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function(){
    $("#myDiv").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "myphpscript.php";

    $.post(url, {contentVar: this.value} ,function(data) {
        $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
        });    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = $('select option:selected').text();
```

Using jQuery's selector syntax, you first select the "select" control, and then the "option" child of the select control. You then look for the selected state. Finally, return the text.

Of course, as is, this code will select every "select" control on the page. It would be better to give your select control an id:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Some option</option>
    <option>Some other option</option>
</select>
```

Then the code becomes

```
var val = $('#mySelect option:selected').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider an [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach and not have the on-change event in your html mark-up, instead attach an event handler as shown below, from the [jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <style>div { color:red; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select name="sweets">
    <option>Chocolate</option>
    <option>Candy</option>
    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>
 </select>
 <div></div>
 <script>
   $("select").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
       str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("div").text(str);
   })
  .change();
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider changing `$("select option:selected");` to `$('option:selected', this);` also, `.each(function() { str += $(this).text() + " "; });` should be `.each(function(k,v) { str += v.text() + " "; });`

Comment: Overall, I think this idea is best, with a few optimizations.

Comment: @crush the code is _more or less_ as it was on the api.jquery site. I haven't changed it as your suggestion in order to keep it consistent with the documentation there - but agree with what you've recommended there.